# My app keeps crashing in android 9 version throwing java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie, android-securityexception

I recently developed an android app that streams radio online using a URL. It has been working well in other android versions that is 6,7and 8 the ones i tested in emulators.

But last week i published the app to play store, and my reports show that it crashes in android 9 phones. It keeps on throwing java.lang.SecurityException.
I have tried what i could to resolve the error but i have failed.
The users keep reporting multiple app crashes on their phones

This is the stack trace from the play console

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3903)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700 (ActivityThread.java:236)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1815)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7032)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:1966)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1934)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1884)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground (IActivityManager.java:5043)
  at android.app.Service.startForeground (Service.java:695)
  at com.premar.radiomunabuddu.RadioMediaPlayerService.play (RadioMediaPlayerService.java:120)
  at com.premar.radiomunabuddu.RadioMediaPlayerService.onStartCommand (RadioMediaPlayerService.java:50)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3884)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: 
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.enforcePermission (ActivityManagerService.java:12159)
  at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.setServiceForegroundInnerLocked (ActiveServices.java:1289)
  at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.setServiceForegroundLocked (ActiveServices.java:969)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.setServiceForeground (ActivityManagerService.java:24839)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$setServiceForeground$ (IActivityManager.java:11378)
```

This is the HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    FancyButton listenRadio;
    ImageView facebook, twitter, instagram, linkedin;
    RadioSettings settings;
    Context context;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE =123;

    private Button stopButton = null;
    private Button playButton = null;
    private Button phoneCall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        settings = new RadioSettings();

        //views
        phoneCall = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.phoneBtn);


        //Allow hardware audio buttons to control volume
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        clickListeners(); //Start click listeners

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    private void openFacebookProfile() {
        try {
            String facebookURL = getFacebookPageUrl();
            Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookURL));
            startActivity(facebookIntent);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getFacebookPageUrl() {
        final String facebookUrl = settings.getFacebookAddress();
        String fbURL = null;
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        try {
            if (packageManager != null){
                Intent fbIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                if (fbIntent != null){
                    int versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana",0).versionCode;
                    if (versionCode >= 3002850){
                        fbURL = "fb://page/1993598950880589";
                    }
                } else {
                    fbURL = facebookUrl;
                }
            }
            else {
                fbURL = facebookUrl;
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fbURL = facebookUrl;
        }
        return fbURL;
    }

    private void openTwitterProfile(){
        Intent intent = null;
        try {
            this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=USERID"));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        } catch (Exception e){
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/profilename"));
        }
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.watch_webcam: {
                launchWebcam();
                break;
            }

            case R.id.playstore_share: {
                /*
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());
                Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
                // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
                goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                try {
                    startActivity(goToMarket);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + context.getPackageName())));
                }
                break;
                */
            }

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

         if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
             String shareMessage= "\nPlease download our Radiomunnabuddu USA app from the Play Store\n\n";
             shareMessage = shareMessage + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +"\n\n";
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT  , shareMessage);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Radio Munnabuddu USA");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via..."));

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_email){
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: "+settings.getEmailAddress()));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Radio Munnabuddu USA");
            if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email via"));
            }
        }
        else if(id == R.id.nav_report){
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: denis@premar.tech"));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Crash or Bug report");
             if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email via."));
             }
         }
        else if(id == R.id.nav_about){
            Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(aboutIntent);
        }
        else if(id == R.id.nav_fb){
            openFacebookProfile();
        }
        else if(id == R.id.nav_twitter){
          openTwitterProfile();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

    }


    /**
     * Listens for contact button clicks
     */
    private void clickListeners(){
        //Play button
        playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.PlayButton);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RadioMediaPlayerService.class);
                intent.putExtra(RadioMediaPlayerService.START_PLAY, true);
                startService(intent);

            }
        });

        //Stop button
        stopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.StopButton);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Get new MediaPlayerService activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RadioMediaPlayerService.class);
                stopService(intent);
            }
        });

        //Email Button click list
        final View EmailPress = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.emailBtn);
        EmailPress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){

                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: "+settings.getEmailAddress()));
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Radio Munnabuddu");
                if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                    try {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });



        //Website Button
        final View WWWPress = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.websiteBtn);
        WWWPress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){

                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(settings.getWebsiteURL())); //URL
                startActivity (browserIntent);

            }
        });

        //SMS Button
        final View TxtPress = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.txtBtn);
        TxtPress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(settings.getSmsNumber());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello Presenter,");
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                /*
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(HomeActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Please grant the permission to call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    requestSMSPermission();
                }
                else {
                    startActivity (smsIntent);
                }*/

            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Launches webcam from external URL
     */
    public void launchWebcam(){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(settings.getRadioWebcamURL()));
        startActivity (browserIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    onCall();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Call Permission Not Granted");
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Call Permission Not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;

            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    public void onCall() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            phoneCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view){
                    /*
                    String phoneNum = settings.getPhoneNumber();
                    Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ phoneNum));
                    if (phoneIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(phoneIntent);
                    }
                    */
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + settings.getPhoneNumber())));
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

This is the RadioMediaPlayerService.java

```
public class RadioMediaPlayerService extends Service implements
        AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {
    //Variables
    private boolean isPlaying = false;
    private MediaPlayer radioPlayer; //The media player instance
    private static int classID = 579; // just a number
    public static String START_PLAY = "START_PLAY";
    AudioManager audioManager;
    //Media session
    MediaSession mSession;

    //Settings
    RadioSettings settings = new RadioSettings();


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Starts the streaming service
     */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(START_PLAY, false)) {

            play();
        }
        //Request audio focus
        if (!requestAudioFocus()) {
            //Could not gain focus
            stopSelf();
        }
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
    }

    /**
     * Starts radio URL stream
     */
    private void play() {

        //Check connectivity status
        if (isOnline()) {
            //Check if player already streaming
            if (!isPlaying) {
                isPlaying = true;

                //Return to the current activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//                mSession.setSessionActivity(pi);

                //Build and show notification for radio playing
                Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.buddu3);
                Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "ID")
                        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                        .setTicker("Radio Munnabuddu USA")
                        .setContentTitle(settings.getRadioName())
                        .setContentText(settings.getMainNotificationMessage())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_radio_black_24dp)
                        //.addAction(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_64dp, "Play", pi)
                       // .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp, "Pause", pi)
                        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                        .setContentIntent(pi)
                        .build();

                //Get stream URL
                radioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    radioPlayer.setDataSource(settings.getRadioStreamURL()); //Place URL here
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                radioPlayer.prepareAsync();
                radioPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        radioPlayer.start(); //Start radio stream
                    }
                });

                startForeground(classID, notification);

                //Display toast notification
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), settings.getPlayNotificationMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            //Display no connectivity warning
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }


    /**
     * Stops the stream if activity destroyed
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stop();
        removeAudioFocus();
    }

    /**
     * Stops audio from the active service
     */
    private void stop() {
        if (isPlaying) {
            isPlaying = false;
            if (radioPlayer != null) {
                radioPlayer.release();
                radioPlayer = null;
            }
            stopForeground(true);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Radio stopped",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    /**
     * Checks if there is a data or internet connection before starting the stream.
     * Displays Toast warning if there is no connection
     * @return online status boolean
     */
    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

        //Invoked when the audio focus of the system is updated.
        switch (focusChange) {
            /*
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                // resume playback
                // if (radioPlayer == null) initMediaPlayer();
                if (radioPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    radioPlayer.release();
                    stopForeground(true);
                }

                radioPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                break;*/
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time: stop playback and release media player
                if (radioPlayer.isPlaying()) radioPlayer.stop();
                radioPlayer.release();
                //radioPlayer = null;
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                // Lost focus for a short time, but we have to stop
                // playback. We don't release the media player because playback
                // is likely to resume
                if (radioPlayer.isPlaying()) radioPlayer.pause();
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing
                // at an attenuated level
                if (radioPlayer.isPlaying()) radioPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * AudioFocus
     */
    private boolean requestAudioFocus() {
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            //Focus gained
            return true;
        }
        //Could not gain focus
        return false;
    }

    private boolean removeAudioFocus() {
        return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==
                audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
    }


}
```

This is the Manifest.xml

```
 <!--uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" /-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!--uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /-->
    <!--tools:node="remove"-->


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <service
            android:name="com.premar.radiomunabuddu.RadioMediaPlayerService"
            android:enabled="true" >

        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.premar.radiomunabuddu.IntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.premar.radiomunabuddu.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.premar.radiomunabuddu.AboutActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.premar.radiomunabuddu.HomeActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android 9 introduced a new `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permission.  From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground):

> Note: Apps that target Android 9 (API level 28) or higher and use foreground services must request the FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission. This is a normal permission, so the system automatically grants it to the requesting app.
>
> If an app that targets API level 28 or higher attempts to create a foreground service without requesting FOREGROUND_SERVICE, the system throws a SecurityException.

Just add that permission to your manifest and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks @Larry, i have applied. I will let you know about the result later

Comment: after adding the above permission, it again throws another android.app.RemoteServiceException: `android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1871)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7032)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)`

Comment: There remote service exception should have some additional details in it about what the service didn't like.

Comment: Is there a way to know which line in the code exactly causing the we error.

Comment: The stack trace should show you the method and line number in most cases.  It can get weird when you have multiple threads or RxJava schedulers, but most of the time you can still track it down.  Provide the full log with the error and me or someone else may be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The setServiceForegroundInnerLocked method will check based on the targetSdkVersion level。lack FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission

code：

```
if (r.appInfo.targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                mAm.enforcePermission(
                        android.Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
                        r.app.pid, r.appInfo.uid, "startForeground");
            }
```